# How can I merge multiple solves from boujou to fusion 8

Tags: video, 3d, tracking

I've been trying to camera solve a specific video file in boujou but everytime I solve it, I get multiple solves. I looked up some tutorials but it seems they use footages that are smooth and high fps but mine isn't, so rather than me trying to prevent the multiple solves which can have many causes, I want to know how to join all the solves into Fusion 8. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?